# Why <hr/> has a strange black top border?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I put a `<hr>` inside of a angular flex divs and the line:

```
<div layout="column" flex>
      <div><hr style="border-color: green; height: 10px; background-color: green;"/></div>
// other divs
</div>
```

[gives me the following result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVOoU.png)

I inspected that div and there's derived `color: black` property, but I override it with `color: green` (there's `color:green` everywhere) yet the result it still the same. Why do I have that strange left & top black (dark green) borders?

Answer (score 2):

Open your inspector (right click on the element and select inspect) and you'll see the user agent stylesheet (the default styles applied to elements by your browser):

```
hr {
    display: block;
    unicode-bidi: isolate;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0.5em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0.5em;
    -webkit-margin-start: auto;
    -webkit-margin-end: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

Notice the `border-style: inset` and `border-width: 1px` default styles applied by the browser.

A lot of people use some sort of reset.css or normalize.css (google these things) to remove a lot of default browser stylings that might be unwanted.

Answer (score 2):

keeping it simple:

```
<hr style=" border: 0;  height: 1px;  background: green;"/>
```

Put any height You like, You have to define the basic **border** of an hr element to be **0** before using it for different features.